# Check if password is correct does not function properly. SQL Statement ERROR

Tags: php, mysql

When trying to receive password to verify that it is correct, i get error:

> [10-May-2017 01:52:44 UTC] PHP Warning:  password_verify() expects
>   parameter 2 to be string, object given in
>   /home/affattraction/login.affattraction.com/admin/login_process.php on
>   line 22

Code is:

```
<?php
/*
*
* Copyright 2017 by Jarrod Estepp
* This script is private software and is illegal to
* use without consent from Jarrod Estepp - hello@jarrodestepp.me
*
* login_process.php
*/
session_start();
include('../includes/settings.php');
include('../includes/mysql.php');

  //Grab Login Details 
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  //Grab Stored Password
$password = $password;
$password_stored = $conn->query("SELECT password FROM admins WHERE email = '$email'");

if(password_verify($password, $password_stored)) {
   echo  "Correct";
} else {
   echo "Your not logged";
}

?>
```

Why am i getting this error. I couldn't find anything to get this resolved!

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in.

Comment: That copyright warning and disclaimer is a bit much, especially for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I will be using prepared statements after tonight. My mentor is going to help me on them.

Comment: @tadman i didn't feel like removing it am so frustrated on why this is not working.

Comment: the moment you post code for everyone to see, it automatically become public domain

Comment: because the $conn->query() returns object .. use `$password_stored['password']`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Technically you can retain copyright even if you publish it here, but it is really odd to slap copyright *DO NOT STEAL* notices on sample code in questions.

Comment: @tadman I'm a bit on the fence with this "copyright" stuff. If they want to retain it, then they shouldn't publish it as source code, IMHO and I'm sure I could find some legal documentation on this on the web ;-)

Comment: i think its a very good warning, as in my view no one should use this code including OP, copyright or not serving the purpose

Comment: @Fred-ii- Copyright is not always as cut and dry as people presume. Everything you write, unless specifically *work-for-hire*, is automatically copyrighted by yourself. This includes code, comments, and Twitter rants. There's presumed licenses when posting in particular contexts, like here it's presumed it's okay to copy/share, due to the site's Terms of Use.

Comment: I mean if someone got on here and seen this post and copied it to use this as a login system reference or just use it i wouldn't care. I put copyright because i am going to be renting this script once i get it made and secure as well as bug checked.

Comment: If anyone wanted to use this code login.php they could have it!

Comment: This isn't the whole entire script this is just login.php and anyone can write something like this

Comment: I **strongly** encourage you to learn from this exercise and **not** sell/rent/license or otherwise distribute this code. You're opening yourself up to massive liabilities if you do because a new PHP developer is wading into a world of hurt on the modern web if they're not backed up by the experience baked into a trusted, well-resepcted framework. Hand-rolled code is *notoriously* bad and many cracking tools can bust it open like a can of beans in seconds. Do you have liability insurance? You're going to need it.

Comment: I do not plan to sell or rent this. This is made for my learning.

Comment: I am making this to learn things i didn't know. This is a personal project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$password_stored = $conn->query("SELECT password FROM admins WHERE email = '$email'");
```

i think that no return data as $password_stored, check again your class and find method like ->row() or something like that to extract the data, example

> $password_stored = $conn->query("SELECT password FROM admins WHERE
>   email = '$email'")->row();
> echo $password_stored->password;

Comment: Okay i think i know what your getting at there now!

Comment: This one fixed my whole situation

Answer (score 1):

Why did you have to re-assign the `$password` variable?

```
$password = $password; /** JUST REMOVE THIS **/
```

You are defying the purpose of prepared statement. And you don't verify the query with the password. You should verify it with the result of the query.

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT password FROM admins WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($password_stored);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

if(password_verify($password, $password_stored)) {
   echo  "Correct";
} else {
   echo "Your not logged";
}
```

Make sure you stored the password using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Thank you so much for adding prepared statement. Now i can look how those are setup to learn them! I appreciate that answer so much!

Answer (score 0):

The result of a `query()` operation is not a string. It's a result. You'll need to call the appropriate `fetch` method on it. Which method depends on if you're using PDO or `mysqli`, your question isn't clear in that regard.

Comment: I am using mysqli

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any help on how i setup to get string?

Comment: As always, [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) is where you start. Like `fetch_array` could be a good option.